# redshift update query with subquery syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-update, amazon-redshift

```
update ca_ger.cln_trans_base 
    set stock_age=cast(week_starting)-b.min_date 
from (
  select pon+season_code as p,min(cast(week_starting as date)) as min_date 
  from ca_ger.cln_trans_base a 
  where a.gross_sales_value>0 
    and aseason_code!='0' 
  group by pon+season_code
) as b;
```

what can be wrong with the above syntax?

Comment: please use a code block for your code and describe your error / issue (edit your question)

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: which records are you updating? all of them? (no where clause)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem `cast(week_starting)`. You need to cast it as something.